# AngularJS filter with ternary operator expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
<td data-ng-repeat="fld in checkedFields" ng-init="field = result[fld.field]; filter = fld.filter">
<span>
    {{ null != filter ? field | filter : field }}
</span>
</td>
```

I am getting the following console error

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '|' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 24 of the expression [null != filter ? field | filter : field] starting at [| filter : field].
```

**Does any know how to use AngularJS filter with ternary operator expression?**

NOTE: fld.filter will be a AngularJS filter

Comment: Can you please add a jsfiddle for the same, want to know what kind of data you have. and syntax does look wrong as ternary operator expects comparison ? true : false ;  and and then you can apply filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use round brackets around the filter expression:

```
{{ null != filter ? (field | filter) : field }}
```

Comment: what is 'filter'? Is it a custom filter? What do you want it to do?

Comment: fld.filter will be a AngularJS filter

Comment: and where is it defined?

Answer (score 2):

In Angularjs **|** is used for applying filters.Try this

```
{{ null != filter ? (field | filter) : field }}
```

Comment: @Dead-Man why you use null to compare ? and in ng-init what value is   filter = fld.filter

Comment: It can be null sometimes

Answer (score 0):

It is barfing on your `|` statement,  that will not work, because `|` is a special char for angular (it means apply a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter))
this is the ternary operator that will work if you are trying to do a regular ternary operator

`{{null != filter ? filter : field}}`

**EDIT**

If you want to apply the filter you will need to do it at the `ng-repeat`

```
<td data-ng-repeat="fld in checkedFields | filterExpression" ng-init="field = result[fld.field]; filter = fld.filter">
<span>
   {{fld.someProperty}}
</span>
</td>
```

you cannot apply your filter on the text you are displaying, and expect the filter to apply to the list. If you are trying to filter you list you will need to modify your code, to apply the filter at the ng-repeat. I have included a link on how filtering works, I recommend looking it over to get a handle on what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ null != filter ? (field || filter) : field }}
```